# SQl server query multiple aggregate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query in sql server to data get like this.

[image: qry]

Essentially it is group by dept, race, gender and then

```
SUM(employees_of_race_by_gender),Sum(employees_Of_Dept).
```

I could get data of first four columns, getting sum of employees in that dept is becoming difficult.
Could you pls help me in writing the query?

All these details in same table Emp. Columns of Emp are Emp_Number, Race_Name,Gender,Dept

Comment: I don't understand where your `num_of_emp_in_race` figures come from? Why does `Latin` fluctuate between `1` and `2` when there are 4 matching rows in the data?

Comment: @Martin Smith: it is by gender too I reckon

Comment: can you specify your result, what result set you are looking for

Comment: @gbn - Still doesn't make sense. Both departments have both a male and female Latin employee but in Executive the desired results are `1,1` and for HR `2,1`

Comment: @Martin Smith: I makes sense to me if you consider all COUNTs are per Dept

Comment: @gbn `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Race_name, Gender)` would return `1` for all rows based on the sample data.

Comment: I read that as output, not input

Comment: @gbn - Ah that makes sense now!

Comment: yes. the image is expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your "num_of_emp_in_race" is actually by Gender too

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Dept,
    Race_name,
    Gender,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Race_name, Gender) AS num_of_emp_in_race,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept) AS num_of_emp_dept
FROM
    MyTable
```

You should probably have this

```
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Gender) AS PerDeptRace
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Race_name) AS PerDeptGender,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Race_name, Gender) AS PerDeptRaceGender,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept) AS PerDept
```

Edit: the DISTINCT appears to be applied before the COUNT (which [would odd based on this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/)) so try this instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        Dept,
        Race_name,
        Gender,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Race_name, Gender) AS num_of_emp_in_race,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept) AS num_of_emp_dept
    FROM
        MyTable
    ) foo
```

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept) AS num_of_emp_dept is not giving total number of employees belonging to a dept. It is instead giving total number of dept rows. For Ex: In the output image, values of last column is 3 for 'Executive' department, but it is also 3 for HR dept.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two sums you're looking for are based on a different aggregation, you need to calculate them separately and join the result. In such cases I first build the selects to show me the different results, making it easy to catch errors early:

```
SELECT Dept, Gender, race_name, COUNT(*) as num_of_emp_in_race
FROM Emp
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3

SELECT Dept, COUNT(*) as num_of_emp_in_dept
FROM Emp
GROUP BY 1
```

Afterwards, joining those two is pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( first statement here ) as by_race
JOIN ( second statement here ) as by_dept ON (by_race.Dept = by_dept.Dept)
```